# Why do I keep getting Syntax Error: JSON parse even though my code works with another API?

Tags: reactjs, api

Working with React and I continually get a SyntaxError:JSON.parse when I try to fetch from the API. I'm able to fetch the data just fine when working with a different API.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm a complete newb when it comes to API's so please don't eviscerate me if this is a stupid question :D

```
   const API_URL = 'www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata';

    const getMealRequest = async()=>{
        const response = await fetch(API_URL)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        getMealRequest()
    },[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error on your API call which is not related to this question. You didn't implement `try/cath` block with the `getMealRequest` so in the failure case, the `response` is not a valid object to parse and you get the mentioned error.

To solve it:

```
const getMealRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata'
)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Now inspect your console and see what is wrong with your API call. also, you can check the network tab for further detail about the request and response on calling `API_URL`.

Comment: So the problem was "unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"  i just added an https:// to the beginning of the link and it worked. Thank you so much for steering me towards the right answer on this! It seems so trivial but I couldn't figure it out for the life of me

Answer (score 0):

```js
const API_URL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata';

const getMealRequest = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL)
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)
}

getMealRequest()
```

You forgot to include protocol:
incude `https://` before the address and it will work: